# TabBarView throwing hasSize error because of height?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I'm trying to implement a `TabBar and TabBarView` into a CustomScrollView widget and its throwing this error:

> RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#ab91d relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

**The issue is definitely the TabBarView and its height.**

**Widget that works:**

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: size.height,
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: this._controller,
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

**Widget that doesn't work**

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: this._controller,
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

The reason why I don't just use the working widget is because I don't want the height to be fixed. I want it to be as much as the its children need. Thats why I tried to use Expanded but it throws the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the entire widget tree if its helps:

```
Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: size.height * 0.45,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: MyImage(),
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text("-_-");,
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                MyInfo(),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              child: TabBar(
                controller: this._controller,
                indicatorColor: primaryCScheme,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.scissors),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.film),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: size.height,            // here is the issue
              color: Colors.red,
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: this._controller,
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Text("Hello"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at Flutter's post about understanding constraints, [which can be found here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints). It's a good resource to understand why you are getting such errors in the first place.

A `SliverToBoxAdapter`, by definition, expects the child to be a box of fixed size.

You can try to give `SliverFillRemaining` a try. It will expand up to the full screen size (when scrolled down past possible other slivers) by default, but you can also set `hasScrollBody` to false to ensure it functions like an `expanded` widget, and doesn't allow for further scrolling.

In the last case, keep in mind the possiblity of the user using the phone in landscape mode.

##### edit

I see there's also `SliverFillViewport`. While I haven't used that myself, I imagine it could be an alternative solution to your problem.

[SliverFillViewport reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillViewport-class.html)

[SliverFillRemaining reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html)